# HP 2000 Time Sharing BASIC Versions

Tags: hp

I used HP 2000F TSB in the mid 1970's during my school years - via a remote dial-up teletype. I've now installed and have working the simh 2000F and Access systems on my computer. I have also installed the Access Contributed Library. These are all working.

However there seems to be differences between the version of Basic for these systems compared to what I used previously. In the version I used there was a user command DUMP to display the contents of variables. Also there was the MLET statement eg, 10 MLET a=1,b=2 and TRACE statement to show line numbers etc as the program was executed. There were also external subroutines using SUB, CALL and LIB statements.

In both the 2000F and Access TSB simh versions these don't seem to be available. I've downloaded and looked at various available TSB manuals and can't find any reference to these extra statements. However I have printouts of some programs from when I used TSB and these do have MLET, SUB, CALL etc statements.

Does anyone have any info as to why these features were available with the TSB version I used in the 1970's compared to the simh versions? Is there a simh version that has these features somewhere that I'm missing? Are there other manuals I haven't found?

Comment: As a general comment - the most recent version of old software that was salvaged is not necessarily the most recent version that ever existed, so it's not entirely surprising that you could have used a version with enhancements not available today.

Comment: It might be exceptional helpful if you could add what version you used back then. Also what software exactly you use now (like with a link)  and what manuals you have so far - otherwise it might be quite hard to see which you have't :))

Comment: @another-dave: It's also possible that later versions of software for a resource-limited machine may omit features which were somewhat useful, but not useful enough to justify the resources needed to support them.  As an example, from what I understand, the version of the Apple II monitor ROM bundled with Integer Basic included an "assemble single-instruction" feature that later versions lack.

Comment: I don't know the exact version I used then -  it was 2000F and not Access. The computer was hosted by the Open University UK. The simh versions are from http://simh.trailing-edge.com/hp/ 2000F rev 1410 and 2000 Access rev 1812. I know that the version of the salvaged software may not be the latest version. But I thought that for the Basic language Access was a superset of 2000F. So even if the 2000F simh version doesn't have these features then I would have expected Access to - but it doesn't. So how come the version I used had these Basic statements but not even Access has them?

Comment: Thinking back, I wonder if the OU had its own version of TSB that supported these extra features? They didn't upgrade from 2000F to Access but replaced the HP system with a DEC System 20 (a much better system IMO). Also the TSB manual we had was published by the OU and not by HP. Does anyone have any info about this please?

Comment: My very first program was in BASIC on the OU system, in the early 1970s (my maths teacher was taking an OU degree in computer science, and let his students play).  I don't recall any MLET statement, but was only writing simplistic code anyway.

Comment: Do any of your saved printouts include signon?  I'd expect the system to announce its name.

Comment: I've found one teletype session that shows the signon. It says The Open University Computing Service From Newcastle Upon Tyne and then just date/time. I have line printer listings that show these extra statements. However the sign on message is the output from the HELLO program in Z999 and was easily customised if you had access to that account.

Comment: Just for my curiosity - was `MLET a=b, b=a` a correctly-executed value swap, or just like `LET a=b; LET b=a`?

Comment: MLET a=b,b=a was the equivalent of LET a=b LET b=a The expressions separated by , were evaluated strictly left to right.  Each expression could be either a numeric or string equate. so MLET a=b,a$="foo",c=3 had a set to b, a$ set to "foo" (assuming a$ had been DIMed for at least 3) and c to 3